# show COLUMNS FROM ma_table with séparator

Tags: php

I want to have the fields names separated with ',' .
This query

```
show COLUMNS FROM ma_table;
```

Returns raw unseparated values

```
$sql = "show COLUMNS from ma_table "; 
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 
while ($rslt = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) { 
    $fields=$rslt['Field']; 
} 
mysql_close();
```

Comment: You need to add your code in also. We cannot help if we cannot see

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: this is my code `$sql = "show COLUMNS  from  ma_table  ";
$req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL!<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 
while ($rslt = mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
$fields=$rslt['Field']; 
}
mysql_close();`

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @sougatabose I dont think that is a particularly good dup for this question. Now OP posted code its just a simple _dont know what I am doing in a while loop issue_

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is concatenate a comma onto `$fields` as you process round the while loop.

You also need to use the `.=` string concatenation operator in the loop so you are adding each new Field to the string and not overwriting it each time.

```
$fields = '';
while ($rslt = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) { 
    $fields .= $rslt['Field'] . ','; 
} 

echo rtrim($fields, ',');
```

> I am afraid I must also add 
>   Every time you use [the `mysql_`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
>    database extension in new code
>    **[a Kitten is strangled somewhere in the world](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-zCT6jizimfI/UjJ5UTb_BeI/AAAAAAAACgg/AS6XCd6aNdg/s1600/luna_getting_strangled.jpg)** it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
>   If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions.
>   [Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)